# "Model is infeasible or unbounded" in Gurobi -- however, this seems to be incorrect

Tags: gurobi

I am new to Gurobi (and solvers in general) and have set up a quadratic non-convex optimization problem by hand in LP file format. The following is a small example that is representative of much larger problems that I will be solving. Gurobi gives "Model is infeasible or unbounded" for this problem. I am setting params.NonConvex = 2 in the model to select the non-convex quadratic solver.

I do understand that having product terms of binary variables is bad form and will be fixing that once I can solve this issue.

```
Minimize
  64   x_1_1 + 100   x_2_1 + 169   x_3_1 + 196   x_4_1  +
  64   x_1_2 + 100   x_2_2 + 169   x_3_2 + 196   x_4_2  - r_1 - r_2

Subject To

  denom1: x_1_1 + x_2_1 + x_3_1 + x_4_1 - d_1 = 0
  denom2: x_1_2 + x_2_2 + x_3_2 + x_4_2 - d_2 = 0


  num1: 8   x_1_1 + 10   x_2_1 + 13   x_3_1 +  14   x_4_1 - n_1 = 0
  num2: 8   x_1_2 + 10   x_2_2 + 13   x_3_2 +  14   x_4_2 - n_2 = 0


  ratio1: [ r_1 * d_1 - n_1 ^ 2 ] = 0
  ratio2: [ r_2 * d_2 - n_2 ^ 2 ] = 0


  item1: x_1_1 + x_1_2 = 1
  item2: x_2_1 + x_2_2 = 1
  item3: x_3_1 + x_3_2 = 1
  item4: x_4_1 + x_4_2 = 1

  bin1: -2   y_1 + [ x_1_1 * y_1 + x_2_1 * y_1 + x_3_1 * y_1 + x_4_1 * y_1 ] >= 0
  bin2: -2   y_2 + [ x_1_2 * y_2 + x_2_2 * y_2 + x_3_2 * y_2 + x_4_2 * y_2 ] >= 0

  empty1: x_1_1 + x_2_1 + x_3_1 + x_4_1 -
          [ x_1_1 * y_1  + x_2_1 * y_1  + x_3_1 * y_1  + x_4_1 * y_1 ] = 0

  empty2: x_1_2 + x_2_2 + x_3_2 + x_4_2 -
          [ x_1_2 * y_2  + x_2_2 * y_2  + x_3_2 * y_2  + x_4_2 * y_2 ] = 0

Binary
  x_1_1 x_2_1 x_3_1 x_4_1
  x_1_2 x_2_2 x_3_2 x_4_2
  y_1 y_2

End
```

All the actual decision variables are binary (the rest, r_1, r_2, n_1, n_2, d_1, d_2 are are computed values from the decision variables) and so the problem cannot be unbounded. The following solution is feasible (and also optimal, based on hand calculation):

```
x_1_1 = 1, x_1_2 = 1, x_1_3 = 0 x_1_4 = 0
x_2_1 = 0, x_2_2 = 0, x_3_2 = 1, x_4_2 = 1
y_1 = 1
y_2 = 1
```

I am wondering why I am getting "Model is infeasible or unbounded" in Gurobi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Model is infeasible or unbounded" is exactly what it sounds like: presolve cannot determine whether the model is infeasible or unbounded. To understand your model better, first set [DualReductions=0](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/dualreductions.html), then solve it again to determine which case it is:

- If it is infeasible, call [computeIIS()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_computeiis.html) to solve the IIS, then find the infeasibilities via the [IISConstr](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/iisconstr.html).
- If it is unbounded, then set [InfUnbdInfo=1](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/infunbdinfo.html), solve, then retrieve the [UnbdRay](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/unbdray.html) attribute to find the unbounded ray.

Comment: Thanks for the presolve tipI set presolve = 0 and Gurobi says that the model is unbounded. Given that all the decision variables are binary, I am unable to see where this unboundedness arises. I then tested the model without r_1 and r_2 in the objective function and Gurobi solved it correctly. However, r_1 and r_2 are directly determined by n_1 and n_2 and d_1 and d_2 which in turn are directly determined by the binary decision variables. Is it OK to have variables in the constraint which are not used in the objective function?

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: UnbdRay seems to be available only for linear models. My model is quadratic and non-convex.

Comment: I added constraints on r_1 and r_2 and Gurobi is able to solve the model. Looks like those two variables are the source of the unboundedness. Need to examine more closely why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. When I ran with presolve = 0, I found that the model was unbounded. From the objective function, it is clear that only r_1 and r_2 could possibly cause this. To confirm, I artificially constrained r_1 and r_2 and Gurobi was able to solve the problem.

Examining the solution that Gurobi gave when I artificially constrained r_1 and r_2 helped me to debug the model. In this formulation, if d_1 and n_1 are 0, then r_1 becomes unbounded (and analogously for d_1 and n_1). Technically it results in division by 0, but Gurobi does not seem to flag this.

Now I have to change the model so that the constraints ratio1 and ratio2 only apply when d_1 and d_2 are respectively non-zero.